# How to obtain many-to-many relationship querys in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am beginner and trying to solve these Queries but didn't get a way can any one please help me.

The following relations keep track of airline flight information :

```
create table flights( 
     flno     number(10) primary key,
     ffrom    varchar2(50),
     fto      varchar2(50),
     distance number(10),
     departs  varchar2(50),
     arrivs   varchar2(50),
     price    number(10,2)
);

create table aircraft(
    aid            number(10)  primary key,
    aname          varchar2(50),
    cruisingrange  number(10)
);

create table employees(
    eid           number(10)  primary key,
    ename         varchar2(50),
    salary        number(10,2)
);
create table certified(
    eid           number(10) references employees(eid),
    aid           number(10) references aircraft(aid)
 );
```

```
flights

+------+-------------+----------+----------+---------+--------+-------+
| Flno |    Ffrom    |   Fto    | Distance | Departs | Arrivs | Price |
+------+-------------+----------+----------+---------+--------+-------+
| 1234 | Los Angeles | Honolulu |     1100 | 9:15    | 21:45  | 25000 |
| 1235 | Los Angeles | Honolulu |     1100 | 11:20   | 22:15  | 15000 |
| 1236 | Los Angeles | Delhi    |     3100 | 6:45    | 23:45  | 25000 |
| 1237 | London      | Newyork  |     2400 | 7:25    | 21:00  | 35000 |
+------+-------------+----------+----------+---------+--------+-------+

aircraft
+-----+-------+---------------+
| aid | aname | cruisingrange |
+-----+-------+---------------+
|   1 | Bb111 |          2000 |
|   2 | Aa123 |          5000 |
|   3 | Aa555 |           900 |
|   4 | Bb777 |           500 |
+-----+-------+---------------+

employees
+-----+-------+--------+
| Eid | Ename | Salary |
+-----+-------+--------+
| 301 | Aaa   |  14000 |
| 302 | Bbb   |  12000 |
| 303 | Ccc   |  25000 |
| 304 | Ddd   |   5000 |
| 305 | Eee   |  50000 |
| 306 | Fff   |  15000 |
| 307 | ggg   |  65000 |
+-----+-------+--------+

certified
+-----+-----+
| Eid | Aid |
+-----+-----+
| 301 |   1 |
| 302 |   3 |
| 303 |   2 |
| 306 |   4 |
| 307 |   1 |
+-----+-----+
```

The Employee relation describes pilots and other kinds of employees as well;
every pilot is certified for some aircraft, and only pilots are certified to fly.

I was trying the following queries

1. Find the names of pilots whose salary is less than the price of the cheapest route from Los Angeles to Honolulu.
2. For all aircraft with cruising range over 1000 miles, find the name of the aircraft and the average salary of all pilots certified for the aircraft.

i tried the query for the first one as

```
 select ename from employees full natural join  certified 
        where 
      salary <(select min(price) from flightsz where   ffrom='los angles' and fto='honolulu');
```

Comment: What did you try and how did it turn out?

Comment: i tried for the first one but i have problem with second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one  would be something like this:

```
 select aircraft.aname,avg(employees.salary) as average  from  aircraft inner join certified on 
  certified.aid =aircraft.aid  inner join employees on employees.eid = certified.eid where aircraft.cruisingrange > 1000
  group by aname
```

Aplying the avg function to a group allows you to get  the average salary.